# Do I need multiple unicorn instances running to serve different rails websites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm new to unicorn,
`digitalocean` default `Rails` configuration seems to only support one rails app at a time.

my unicorn config currently looks like this:

```
listen "127.0.0.1:8080"  
worker_processes 2  
user "rails"  
working_directory "/home/rails"  
pid "/home/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"  
stderr_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"  
stdout_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
```

unicorn process is set to start automatically on startup in `/etc/init.d/unicorn`

is it possible to specify multiple applications, listening on different ports/unix sockets or do they need to be separate unicorn processes, I need them start automatically on startup

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Each unicorn holds the code for one Rails application. So if you want to run multiple Rails apps, you need multiple unicorn master processes (each spawning children).

You can easily create different startup-scripts (`/etc/init.d/unicorn-app1`, `/etc/init.d/unicorn-app2` …) for these unicorns as long as lockfiles, pidfiles and ports don't clash.